# scrollbar div size of page height

Tags: html, css

I have a dashboard left, and need that dashboard to be in the same size of the page, everytime it needs to get bigger i want to apply the scroll, at the moment i am doing something like this:

```
style="overflow-y: scroll; height:450px;"
```

this is applied to all my section, the thing here is that i set the height a value, i tried with height auto and 100%, but without success, any help with this?

my page is getting bigger because of that dashboard if i cant mantain the page size and give it a scroll it would help a lot

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set the min-height:100%

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this appropriate.

```css
body{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.a{
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width: 20%;
height:100vw;
overflow:auto;
background-color:purple;
padding:0;
margin:0}

.b{display:block;
width:80%;
background-color:pink;
padding:0;
margin-left:20%;

min-height:100vw}
```

```html
<div class="a">

</div>
<div class="b">
  content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use height: 100vh; // viewport height
Check compatibility here
http://www.caniuse.com/#search=vh

And if you want to support old browsers calculate "$(window).height()" and assign it to this div